# PowerPivot and SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, powerpivot

Can PowerPivot connect to an SSRS 2008 R2 server without SharePoint (Native mode)? Would like to load from SSRS but seems to not want to connect from PowerPivot. Is there some type of configuration I need to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no special configuration required, you simply need access to the report.

In Excel 2013, choose Get External Data > From Other Sources, and then under Data Feeds, choose Report and then enter the URL of the report in the box. You will then be prompted to select the tablix / dataset to import into PowerPivot.

Comment: Thanks. I will try again, and I was using 2010, so will attempt with 2013